# Publishing a ClickOnce Winforms app in an unreliable network environment

Tags: .net, visual-studio, clickonce, publish, unreliable-connection

From time to time I am publishing a corporate app to our satellite branch in India.  The connection is quite poor, and I struggle with performing a basic ClickOnce publish (the publish built in to VS2017).  The system will try to publish but hang maybe 10% of the way through.  Sometimes I get to 90%!

I have to try 5 or 10 times before I get enough of a stable connection to send over the files.  We are only talking 150 MB here.  Any ideas on how to make VS work with an unreliable connection? I would think Microsoft would have error correction / retry mechanisms to alleviate this.

Answer (score 2):

ClickOnce is just a directory on disk. You could publish to a local directory and then use a more robust tool (Rsync for example) to get the files over. There is no magic whatsoever with ClickOnce (at least last time I used it which was well over five years ago).